# Powershell: check if computer logged out

Tags: powershell

I need what I hope is a very simple way to do this in Powershell (I'm running the Powershell scripts remotely using Absolute Manage):

```
if ( computer is logged out )
 {
    <run script>
 }
 else
 {
    exit
 }
```

Most of what I've found while searching revolves around doing something much more complicated related to user logins/logouts. I basically just need to know if the computer is currently sitting at the login prompt or not.

Thanks for any and all assistance -- you guys are awesome.

Answer (score 0):

Depending upon your environment this can be a minefield as discussed here:

[Scripting Guy Article](http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2011/03/17/use-powershell-to-detect-if-a-workstation-is-in-use.aspx)

In summary, use the PSLoggedOn tool available from the [SysInternals Suite](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb842062.aspx) whilst being careful to filter out any service accounts which may be returned.  To guard against link rot here's the usage example from the above Scripting Guy article:

```
$Computers = @( 
,   "PC001" 
,   "PC002" 
,   "PC003" 
,   "PC004" 
)

Foreach ($Computer in $Computers) 
{ 
    [object[]]$sessions = Invoke-Expression ".\PsLoggedon.exe -x -l \\$Computer" | 
        Where-Object {$_ -match '^\s{2,}((?<domain>\w+)\\(?<user>\S+))|(?<user>\S+)'} | 
        Select-Object @{ 
            Name='Computer' 
            Expression={$Computer} 
        }, 
        @{ 
            Name='Domain' 
            Expression={$matches.Domain} 
        }, 
        @{ 
             Name='User' 
             Expression={$Matches.User} 
         } 
    IF ($Sessions.count -ge 1) 
    { 
        Write-Host ("{0} Users Logged into {1}" –f $Sessions.count,     
            $Computer) -ForegroundColor 'Red' 
    } 
    Else 
    { 
        Write-Host ("{0} can be rebooted!" -f $Computer) ` 
            -ForegroundColor 'Green' 
    } 
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

As described [here](http://www.peetersonline.nl/?p=98), you can use the snippet below to get all logged on users. Note that this will contain users such as SYSTEM, LOCAL SERVICE, and NETWORK SERVICE.

```
Get-WmiObject Win32_LoggedOnUser -ComputerName "myMachine" | 
    Select Antecedent -Unique | 
    % { 
        "{0}\{1}" -f $_.Antecedent.Split('"')[1], $_.Antecedent.Split('"')[3]
    }
```

If you want to look only for people in certain domains, you can modify it slightly like this:

```
Get-WmiObject Win32_LoggedOnUser -ComputerName "myMachine" | 
    Select Antecedent -Unique | 
    % { 
        $domain = $_.Antecedent.Split('"')[1]
        if($domain -eq "myDomain") {
            "{0}\{1}" -f $domain, $_.Antecedent.Split('"')[3]
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Using WMI if possible:

```
$info = gwmi -class win32_computerSystem -computer sist002ws -ea silentlycontinue | Select-Object username

if ($info.username.Length -gt 0)

{$Message = $info.username}
else
{ $Message = "No user is logged in locally"}

$message
```

Answer (score 0):

This will get you all Interactive/RemoteInteractive (Terminal Services session) logged on users. You may want to add more LogonType's to the filter. No result means no one is logged in.

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa394189(v=vs.85).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa394189%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

```
Get-WmiObject Win32_LogonSession -ComputerName Server1 -Filter 'LogonType=2 OR LogonType=10' | 
Foreach-Object { $_.GetRelated('Win32_UserAccount') } |
Select-Object Caption -Unique
```